# Datatables refresh with draw(), ajax, pagination

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to refresh my table with data from the server every few seconds.  It's loading the new data but the pagination is not working at all. By that I mean, it's one big list of the data. It's also saying `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)` for the pagination at the bottom of the table.

I am using [draw(false)](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()#Examples%20%60draw%60) in a `setInterval` function to achieve the refresh.  I wanted to do this without using `"serverSide":"true"` but I found that `draw()` doesn't call the `ajax` url unless I use the `serverSide` option.

```
function myFunction() { 
var table1 = $("#example1").dataTable({
    "ajax": '/api/GetData',
    "serverSide": "true",
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "DateCreated",                
        },
        { "data": "UserName" }
    ],
    "destroy": true
});

setInterval(function test() {        
    table1.draw(false);
}, 3000);
}
```

When I omit `"serverSide":"true"` the table is drawn correctly with the pagination but the ajax is not called with `draw()`.  How can I get the ajax data and have the pagination set correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [ajax.reload()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) to reload the table data from the Ajax data source with `false` as a second parameter to avoid resetting current paging position.

```
table1.api().ajax.reload(null, false);
```

Since your table is initialized using `dataTable()`, API methods can be accessed with `table1.api()` method. Otherwise, if table is initialized using `DataTable()`, API methods can be accessed using `table1` directly. See [DataTables API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  I searched for a while and this didn't come up, only the draw function.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your AJAX function is returning: sEcho, iTotalRecords, iTotalDisplayRecords and iDisplayLength.

Also, set "iDisplayLength": 500, at client-side when you call dataTable function.

You can read more about these parameters on https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/512/clarification-of-itotalrecords-and-itotaldisplayrecords

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this link applies the older version of datatables but I think there is the same thing in 1.10.